# Subtracting days in new Date() in a view

Tags: javascript, extjs, datefield

I got this piece of code:

```
    xtype: 'datefield',
    editable: false,
    itemId: 'start-date-field',
    fieldLabel: 'Från',
    labelWidth: 50,
    format: 'Y-m-d',
    value: new Date(),
    disabled: true
```

and I'm trying to subtract some days from "new Date()" but my googlefu isn't good enought and this is probably easy enough for most people. I've tried new Date().getDay - 30 but that only generates an error.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Comment: new Date().getDate()+1 works but not -1, why?

Comment: It does, see my answer below.

Comment: You added a function I was just wondering why new Date().getDate()-30 don't works.

Comment: Well, it also "works", in a way, but not in the way you are expecting. I "explained" it in my answer comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xtype: 'datefield',
editable: false,
itemId: 'start-date-field',
fieldLabel: 'Från',
labelWidth: 50,
format: 'Y-m-d',
value: (function() {var lastMonth = new Date(); return lastMonth.setDate(lastMonth.getDate()-30), lastMonth;})(),
disabled: true
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzvga0os/1/)

Comment: Thanks it works, but why can't I use my solution that I suggested above in the comments?

Comment: Well, because `new Date().getDate()+1` is parsed as `(new Date()).getDate()+1`, whereas `new Date().getDate()-1` is parsed as `(new Date().getDate())-1`. Not really sure why, though.

Comment: So should it work if i type in (new Date()).getDate()-1 instead without the compiler parsing it? Or will the compiler just compile it further?

Comment: Actually, it does not matter, you will always get the date (i.e. the day of the month) with Date#getDate();